# Associated Euler differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to figure out what the associated Euler equation for $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+p(p+1)y=0$ (1) at $x=1$. would look like. We know that the general form of the Cauchy-Euler equation is $ax^2 y'' + bxy' +cy = 0$. But I don't seem to be able to figure out how one can transform (1) into this form. I would appreciate some ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equation is the Legendre differential equation. It has regular singular points at $x=\pm 1$. Divide by the coefficient of the highest order derivative:
$$
           y''-\frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}y'+\frac{p(p+1}{1-x^{2}}y = 0.
$$
To consider this equation near $x=1$, you have to expand the coefficients in powers of $x-1$. For example,
$$
        -\frac{2x}{1-x^{2}}=\frac{2x}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{1}{(x-1)}\left[\frac{2x}{1+x}\right]
$$
Now expand $f(x)=2x/(1+x)$ about $x=1$:
$$
           f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+\frac{f''(1)}{2!}(x-1)^{2}+\cdots.
$$
You only need the $1/(x-1)$ singular term. Clearly $f(1)=1$. So
$$
          y'' +\left[\frac{1}{x-1}+C+D(x-1)+\cdots\right]y'+\frac{p(p+1)}{1-x^{2}}y=0.
$$
For the $y$ term, you only need the coefficient of $\frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}$, which is $0$ in this case. So the associated Euler equation is
$$
              (x-1)^{2}y''+(x-1)y' + 0y = 0.
$$
This has solution $(x-1)^{\rho}$ where
$$
              \rho(\rho-1)(x-1)^{2}+\rho(x-1)(x-1) = 0\\
              \rho(\rho-1)+\rho = 0 \\
                \rho^{2}=0.
$$
The other solution of the Euler equation is a logarithmic term.

Comment: Do you have a reference for more examples and explanations?